# Website loads pefectly local but only title on network

Tags: linux, tomcat, web, clojure

I've built a website using Clojure (Luminus Framework) and I've deployed to Tomcat 9.0 to a Linux server.

I've done this at the company network and I am able to surf the website using http://localIP:8080 and http://externalIP:8080

But I'm installing in a client network, same Linux distribution (Debian), same Tomcat 9 and Java version (1.8).

The problem is that I can surf the web site through http://localIP:8080 but when I go to http://externalIP:8080 it loads only the title/header partially (see the imagem below).

External access
[image: External access]

Internal access
[image: Internal access]

I couldn't figure it out through tomcat logs, the output are the same as in my network.

Im guessing it is some kind of port or ip conflict, but how can I kind of debug this? I do not have control to this network, because it is from a client.

I appreciate in advance.

**EDIT**

After some tests, I got something.

This is my rendering function:

```
(layout/render
          "trocar-senha.html" {:request      request
                               :titulo       (slurp (io/resource "docs/titulo.txt") :encoding "UTF-8")
                               :nome_empresa (slurp (io/resource "docs/nome_empresa.txt"))
                               :site_empresa (slurp (io/resource "docs/site_empresa.txt"))
                               :warning      "Senha atual não confere com senha cadastrada no sistema."})
```

I reduced to 2 keys (only request and titulo) and it worked. But why? It works locally. And I need all keys.

Comment: I believe, You could mix up some of url in a code or in html. for example, if you use your resources(js scripts, pic etc) via "localhost:port/resource_path/resource" then it would work locally, but wouldn't work in outside network

Comment: In the DB connection im usin localip:port/db, and the resources path in clojure is referred into project.clj through key :resource-paths ["resources"]. And in my company, I can acces both via local and external IP addres, but not when installed in my client

Comment: Developer tools in your browser might provide information to help troubleshoot.

Comment: I checked but got nothing. I've ran some tests and something came up. In my render function I have `(layout/render "home.html" {:request request :title website :website website :text text :name name})` but if I reduce it to 2 or 3, it works fine. But why? I need all of them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The network was blocking the website due to a Facebook link in the header image.

After removing it, it works perfectly.

So, always check for the network limitations.